# Chromeの拡張機能開発でJavaScriptの「location.href」が正しく動作しない

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, chrome-extension

プログラミング初心者です。
現在、Chromeの拡張機能開発を行っています。

Chromeの拡張機能をクリックするだけで、閲覧中のWEBサイトのURLを取得し、別タブでWEBサイトの表示速度が測定できる「Google PageSpeed Insights」に取得したURLが自動的に反映されるプログラムを制作しています。

完成イメージとしては、閲覧中のサイト（stackoverflow）でChromeの拡張機能をクリックすることで、
[image: stackoverflow.com]

「Google PageSpeed Insights」のサイト内にある、URL入力欄に取得したURLが自動的に反映されるプログラムです。
[image: developers.google.com]

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

javascriptの「location.href」を活用して、閲覧中のサイトのURLを取得しようとしたのですが、うまくいきません。

閲覧中のサイトのURLを「https://○○○」の形で取得できず、
「chrome-extension://afodfheljgloicekcifhieopgnbpibjm/_generated_background_page.html」の形で取得してしまいます。

#### 該当のソースコード

**manifest.json**

```
﻿{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "page speed checker",
  "version": "2.0",
  "description": "閲覧中のサイトの表示速度を測定します",
  "icons": {
    "128": "page.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "page speed checker",
    "default_icon": "page.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["contents.js"]
  },

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

**contents.js**

`chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {void(window.open('https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url='+location.href));});`

原因がわかる方がいましたら、教えていただきたいです。

javascriptの「location.href」を使わない方が簡単にできるなどのご意見もありましたら、
お伝えいただけると嬉しいです。

何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chromeの拡張機能で現在開いているページを取得するために`location.href`を使用することはできません。
理由は少し難しいですが、「拡張機能のJavaScriptコードが動いているページ」と「ブラウザが現在開いているページ」が異なるためです（`location.href`で取得されるのは後者ではなく前者）。

実はお使いの`chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener`APIではコールバック引数の第一引数として現在のタブを表す[Tabオブジェクト](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab)が与えられています。
その`url`プロパティを調べることで現在のURLを得ることができます。具体的には以下のコードのように行います。

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {                                                                                         
    // 現在開いているURLを取得
    var url = tab.url;                                                                                                                             
    // 試しに表示してみる                                                                                                                    
    console.log(url);                                                                                                                              
    // Google PageSpeed Insightsを開く                                                                                                             
    window.open('https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url='+url);                                                               
});
```

---

また、多少ややこしいものの、`location.href`を用いる別の方法として[chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript)を用いる方法もあるので一応紹介いたします。
これは現在開いているページで特定のJavascriptコードを実行するものです。`window.open`を実行するコードを実行してやることで、`location.href`を用いて目的の動作をさせることができます。コードを文字列で与えている点が少し難しいので注意してください。

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: `
            window.open('https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url='+location.href);
        `,
    });
});
```

---

どちらの方法も、browser action内で[activeTabパーミッション](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab)が与えられることを利用しています。manifest.json内の`permissions`内は`"tabs"`ではなく`"activeTab"`としても動作すると思います。

Comment: Faily Feelyさん回答ありがとうございます。無事に解決しました。

解説とてもわかりやすくかったです。
プログラミング初心者の僕でも内容を把握できました。

別の実行手段に対しても解説いただき、大変感謝しております。
プログラミング初心者でわからないことだらけですが、これから先も頑張ります。